# mysql count distinct variable more than 1

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I need to select all `idemploye` that have work on more than 1 project

I have tried:

```
select idemploye from ressourcesprojet where (disctint idemploye>1);
```

but i got an error. Can somebody please help me with this?

```
RessourcesProjet

idprojet  /  idemploye     
1         /        389    
1         /        811    
2         /        389    
2         /        523    
3         /        811    
3         /        987
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT idemploye 
FROM ressourcesprojet
GROUP BY idemploye
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

UPDATE: Here is a working [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df6ad/2/0)

Comment: @MarioBoulanger .  .  . This should not be working, because it is grouping by `idprojet`, not `idemploye`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right, my bad, that was my intent, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you want:

```
SELECT idemploye 
FROM ressourcesprojet
GROUP BY idemploye
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT idproject) >= 2;
```